# Inverse Limit Space (Homeomorphism)

Tags: general-topology

The problem is...

Suppose that $X = \lim_\leftarrow \{X_i, f_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is an inverse limit space so that there is an integer $N$ and for each $n \geq N$ the function $f_n$ is an onto homeomorphism. Then $X$ is homeomorphic to $X_N$.

Can't we just define a map $f: X \rightarrow X_N$ to be $f(P) = P_N$, where $P=\{P_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty} \in X$? Won't this be a homeomorphism? Why do we need an integer $N$ that satisfies such conditions? Where do I use that the $f_n$'s are onto homeomorphisms?

Comment: You just used it to define $f$.

Comment: Well yes... but what I mean is, why do we need such an N that satisfies the conditions given. Couldn't I use the f I gave as a homeomorphism between X and any of the Xi's?

Comment: $f_n: X_{n+1} \to X_n$?

Comment: If, say, $X_N$ has two or more points, and if $f_{N-1} : X_N \to X_{N-1}$ is a constant map, then certainly the map $f : X \to X_{N-1}$ given by $f(P)=P_{N-1}$ will not be a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Throughout I assume that we are talking about the concrete topological realization of the inverse limit, namely as [a special subset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_limit#Formal_definition) of the product space.

So you claim that the natural projection is a homeomorphism. Obviously that needs a proof. So lets construct the inverse $g:X_N\to X$. Note that $g(x)$ is a sequence. Denote by $g(x)_k$ its $k$-th coordinate. Define:

$$g(x)_{N+k}=f_{N+k-1}^{-1}\circ\cdots\circ f_N^{-1}(x)$$
$$\vdots$$
$$g(x)_{N+2}=f_{N+1}^{-1}(f_N^{-1}(x))$$
$$g(x)_{N+1}=f_N^{-1}(x)$$
$$g(x)_N=x$$
$$g(x)_{N-1}=f_{N-1}(x)$$
$$g(x)_{N-2}=f_{N-2}(f_{N-1}(x))$$
$$\vdots$$
$$g(x)_{N-k}=f_{N-k}\circ\cdots\circ f_{N-1}(x)$$

Can you see why I've defined $g$ like this? $f_i$ obviously have to be homeomorphisms for $i\geq N$ in order for $g$ to be well defined and continuous.

Note that this is crutial. Without these assumptions the natural projection need not be a homeomorphism and often is not.

**Side note:** A function is not just formula. You seem to think that the natural projection does not depend on $f_i$ because its formula doesn't. **This is wrong**. It very much does, because **the domain does**. And so properties of the natural projection depend on $f_i$. Similarly the projection onto first coordinate $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ is not a homeomorphism but the same projection $\mathbb{R}\times\{1\}\to\mathbb{R}$ is. A function is made up of three things: formula, domain and codomain. And this is a great example of that fact.

Comment: Thank you.. this is very helpful. I think I am not having a good understanding of this topological space... as far as points in the space, open sets, etc. My class in taught with the Moore Method, and the definition given for "inverse limit space" is what he calls it, is not quite like the ones I find online. Would you happen to know of a good resource for this?

Comment: @HJoy AFAIK there are only two approaches to inverse limits: categorical and concrete. In the concrete case (which is ours) it is simply a subset $A\subseteq \prod_{i\in I} X_i$ such that for any $a\in A$ we have $a_i=f_{ij}(a_j)$. Here it is generalized a bit since your maps are single-indexed. But when indexing system is $\mathbb{N}$ it is the same thing. The topology is then a subspace topology of the product topology. I don't know any specific resource, I guess you can google any, they all seem to give the same thing. What is your definition of the inverse limit?

Comment: It is given as follows.. "For each positive integer $i$ let $X_i$ be a topological space and let $f_i: X_i+1 \rightarrow X_i$ be a continuous map. Then the inverse limit space
$X = lim^{\leftarrow}\{X_i, f_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$
is defined as follows.
The element $P = \{P_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$
is a point of $X$ provided for each positive integer
$i, P_i \in X_i$ and $f_i(P_i+1) = P_i$. If $U_i$ is a subset of $X_i$ then
$U_i^{\leftarrow} = \{P \in X : P_i \in U_i\}$. The collection $B = \{U_i^{\leftarrow} : U_i$ is open in $X_i ;i = 1, 2, ...\}$ is a basis for the topology for $X$."

Comment: @HJoy Yes, these are same definitions. Formally $P\in\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} X_i$ is a special sequence, so your $X$ is a special subset of $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} X_i$. Topologies then coincide. My construction will work for both of them. The point is that $X$ is a subspace of $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} X_i$ and so the universal property of product topology will be helpful in showing that $g$ is continuous. In short: $g$ is continuous if and only if each coordinate is continuous.